# Can't server mute someone using discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Basically whenever I run this code it gives me an error, I am trying to make the code server mute one of my friends every 20 seconds for 5 seconds, it says there is something wrong with the line where the user is being defined.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
import random
import datetime
from datetime import date
import calendar
import time
import asyncio
from discord.ext.tasks import loop


client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.')


@tasks.loop(seconds=20)
async def mute_person():
  user = await discord.Guild.fetch_member("670549896247509002", "670549896247509002")  # Get the Member Object
  await user.edit(mute=True)  # Mute
  await asyncio.sleep(20)  # Waits for 20 seconds then unmute.
  await user.edit(mute=False)  # Unmute

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print("I am ready")
  mute_person.start()


client.run("Token")
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the right function `discord.Guild` doesn't exist as you are using it. the main use must be `await guild.fetch_member(member_id)` and then `guild` means the guild object which has a specific ID as well. So you need to get the guild first.

Comment: How can I get the guild first?